# How do I refactor this code using ramda.js?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm using `mithril.js` and `ramda.js`. I have the following code in mithril:

```
return m('ul.list-inline.text-center', [
     ctrl.items.map(item => R.allPass(item.policies)(item) ? m('li', m('a', {
          href: item.uri,
          config: m.route
      }, item.name)) : null)
]);
```

So basically I'm iterating over `ctrl.items` and `item.policies` is just an array of simple functions returning `true / false`. Therefore, `R.allPass(item.policies)(item)` gives me either `true` if everything passes or `false` otherwise and then this decides whether to render `li` tag or not.

So instead of this functionality, I thought it would be better to create this more functional way as I will be able to reuse the code. So instead of map, I thought I would `filter` down the items using that `R.allPass` and then just render out the filtered array instead.

I started fiddling around with a simple filter in ramda, but I cannot figure out how to achieve the result:

```
var filterItems = R.filter(
    R.pipe(
        R.prop('policies'),
        R.allPass               
    )
);
```

This just returns the full array. It doesn't exclude any items at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from what I can make of your types, the issue is that you're expecting a function to do double-duty.

Assuming `items` contains a list of objects such as this:

```
const items = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    val: 13,
    policies: [
      obj => obj.val > 10,
      obj => obj.val < 20,
      obj => obj.val % 2 == 1,
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    val: 14,
    policies: [
      obj => obj.val > 10,
      obj => obj.val < 20,
      obj => obj.val % 2 == 1,
    ]
  }
];
```

then this:

```
R.pipe(
    R.prop('policies'),
    R.allPass               
)
```

will have a type something like:

```
const testPolicies = R.pipe(
    R.prop('policies'), // :: Item -> [(Item -> Boolean)]
    R.allPass           // :: [(Item -> Boolean)] -> Item -> Boolean
)                    // => :: Item -> Item -> Boolean
```

You need to pass two copies of your item to this function to get it to return a boolean.  But you treat it as though it would work with just one, as though it could serve as an input to `filter :: (Item -> Boolean) -> [Item] -> [Item]`.

You need a way to transform your `(Item -> Item -> Boolean)` into a `(Item -> Boolean)`.

There is nothing built into Ramda to help with this, although perhaps Ramda should consider adding this, as it's occasionally useful.  But one of the standard combinators<sup>1</sup>, known as `W` would do this:

```
const W = f => x => f(x)(x);
```

You could then use it like this:

```
R.filter(W(testPolicies), items); //=>
// {
//   name: 'foo',
//   val: 13,
//   policies: [
//     obj => obj.val > 10,
//     obj => obj.val < 20,
//     obj => obj.val % 2 == 1,
//   ]
// }
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.21.0#?code=const%20items%20%3D%20[%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27foo%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20val%3A%2013%2C%0A%20%20%20%20policies%3A%20[%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%20%3D%3E%20obj.val%20%3E%2010%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%20%3D%3E%20obj.val%20%3C%2020%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%20%3D%3E%20obj.val%20%25%202%20%3D%3D%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20]%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27bar%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20val%3A%2014%2C%0A%20%20%20%20policies%3A%20[%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%20%3D%3E%20obj.val%20%3E%2010%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%20%3D%3E%20obj.val%20%3C%2020%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20obj%20%3D%3E%20obj.val%20%25%202%20%3D%3D%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20]%0A%20%20%7D%0A]%3B%0A%0Aconst%20testPolicies%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20R.prop%28%27policies%27%29%2C%0A%20%20R.allPass%0A%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20W%20%3D%20f%20%3D%3E%20x%20%3D%3E%20f%28x%29%28x%29%3B%0A%0AR.filter%28W%28testPolicies%29%2C%20items%29)**.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a nice list of combinators in **[Avaq's gist](https://gist.github.com/Avaq/1f0636ec5c8d6aed2e45)**.